# how to strip html tags from a drupal token

Tags: php, drupal

I have a drupal token of the form [content: message]. How do i strip html tags from the output that it returns.  Ideally i want to have `strip_tags($var)` operation to be performed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why can't you just use `strip_tags($drupaltokenvariable)`?

Comment: so if my token is '[content: content-body]' i should use something like 'strip_tags($content->body)'?

Comment: Well, I'm not entirely sure about the actual syntax, but yeah, whatever the variable for the content is, put inside `strip_tags();`